# Strange behavior of javascript RegExp: same regular expressions produce different result

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why RegExp with global flag in Javascript give wrong results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results)

```
var reg1 = new RegExp('^http:\/\/abc\.com\/\d+$');
var reg2 = /^http:\/\/abc\.com\/\d+$/;

var url = 'http://abc.com/1657706754';

// expected: true, actual: false
document.write(reg1.test(url));
document.write('<br/>');
// expected: true, actual: true
document.write(reg2.test(url));
```

​See the above code sample. `reg1` and `reg2` are same regular expressions, but why the `test` results are different? I test it in Chrome. Here's the online demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DzfWC/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use it as a literal string you must escape every `\`  with `\\`:

```
var reg1 = new RegExp('^http:\\/\\/abc\\.com\\/\\d+$');
```

Comment: Thanks! Bad javascript, it should have thrown some Error for this. :(